# Performance difference between DISTINCT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, distinct

My understanding is that in (My)SQL a `SELECT DISTINCT` should do the same thing as a `GROUP BY` on all columns, except that `GROUP BY` does implicit sorting, so these two queries should be the same:

```
SELECT boardID,threadID FROM posts GROUP BY boardID,threadID ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 100;
SELECT DISTINCT boardID,threadID FROM posts LIMIT 100;
```

They're both giving me the same results, and they're giving identical output from `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1263320 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
1 row in set
```

But on my table the query with `DISTINCT` consistently returns instantly and the one with `GROUP BY` takes about 4 seconds. I've disabled the query cache to test this.

There's 25 columns so I've also tried creating a separate table containing *only* the boardID and threadID columns, but the same problem and performance difference persists.

I *have* to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` so I can include additional columns without them being included in the evaluation of `DISTINCT`. So now I don't how to proceed. Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your queries are not quite the same - GROUP BY has ORDER BY, but DISTINCT does not.

Note, that in either case, index is NOT used, and that cannot be good for performance.

I would suggest creating compound index for `(boardid, threadid)` - this should let both queries to make use of index and both should start working much faster

**EDIT**: Explanation why `SELECT DISTINCT ... LIMIT 100` is faster than `GROUP BY ... LIMIT 100` when you do not have indexes.

To execute first statement (`SELECT DISTINCT`) server only needs to fetch 100, maybe slightly more rows and can stop as soon as it has 100 different rows - no more work to do.
This is because original SQL statement did not specify any order, so server can deliver any 100 rows as it pleases, as long as they are distinct. But, if you were to impose any index-less `ORDER BY` on this before `LIMIT 100`, this query will immediately become slow.

To execute second statement (`SELECT ... GROUP BY ... LIMIT 100`), MySQL always does implicit `ORDER BY` by the same columns as were used in GROUP BY. In other words, it cannot quickly stop after fetching first few 100+ rows until all records are fetched, groupped and sorted. After that, it applies `ORDER BY NULL` you added (which does not do much I guess, but dropping it may speed things up), and finally, it gets first 100 rows and throws away remaining result. And of course, this is damn slow.

When you have compound index, all these steps can be done very quickly in either case.

Comment: Well it made no difference to the original query whether it had the `ORDER BY NULL` with the `DISTINCT` or not, so I left it out. But you're right about the index. That's made both the queries equally fast. I'm still interested to know why there's an apparent difference in execution, but the additional index has cleared up the practical problem. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your explanation, it's a very good hypothesis but it doesn't seem to fit with what I'm seeing. If I leave out the `ORDER BY NULL` then the `GROUP BY` query is sorted (and `EXPLAIN` agrees: "Using filesort", it says) but with `ORDER BY NULL`, the result of both queries is fully identical with the rows in the same chaotic order as the raw rows in the table. So `GROUP BY` *should* be able to stop after 100 distinct rows. It should find the 100th distinct row after looking at just 3784 of them, but Filemon shows it's reading all of the 300 MB table file. Perhaps it's simply a bug.